# BuildFire: buildfire is not defined

Tags: buildfire

I have created a plugin for an app, that is working perfectly fine in local machine and on app.buildfire. But when I have published my changes and tried testing on device I am getting below error.

```
04-27 10:32:33.741 6512-6512/? I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(173)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: buildfire is not defined", source: file:///data/user/0/com.bf.app698324/files/files/pluginTemplate/plugins/84dad72d-0641-4ebd-8349-ff9bd3d7c2b6/widget/index.html?fid=pluginFrame0.3707975031273656&v=1556341353636 (173)
```

Below is the path for buildfire.min.js setup in my index.html file in widget folder.

```
<script src="../../../../scripts/buildfire.min.js"></script>
```

I don't know why buildfire is not defined, my guess was if it is working perfectly on app.buildfire.com then it should work on device too.

I need your help guys, if there is some other path for this for release purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find out an answer for this.

When we are publishing our plugin, buildfire resources are available at one level down as compared to it's SDK hierarchy. So instead of below line :

```
<script src="../../../../scripts/buildfire.min.js"></script>
```

We have to include below line in order to make our plugin work :

```
<script src="../../../scripts/buildfire.min.js"></script>
```

This issue is happening with SDK 1.19.3

Comment: There are two different levels for Widget and Control. Are you sure you didn't copy one path into another?

Comment: Nope I didn't... So it means for Widgets path should be `<script src="../../../scripts/buildfire.min.js"></script>` and for controls path should be `<script src="../../../../scripts/buildfire.min.js"></script>`